# Jquery image slider not working properly onLoad

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I have use Jquery to slide images. However Images slide but there are some problem. I have 4 images. When page loads it shows 4th image first & when image slides 4th image stays onScreen and sliding images just flashes up there. Once all 4 images slided then from second round they all work fine. Here is the link [click](http://foxboxretail.com/). Please view this link to know exact problem..

html

```html
<div class="main-banner">
  <div id="slideshow">
    <div class="slideImg">
      <img src="images/Gift-a-spa.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="slideImg">
      <img src="images/Gift-A-Shopping.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="slideImg">
      <img src="images/Gift-a-Skill-Learn.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="slideImg">
      <img src="images/Indoor-Sports.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!--main-banner-ends-->
```

jquery

```js
$("#slideshow > .slideImg:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function () {
  $('#slideshow > .slideImg:first')
  .fadeOut(1000)
  .next()
  .fadeIn(1000)
  .end()
  .appendTo('#slideshow');
}, 3000);
```

css

```css
.main-banner {
  background: #444;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height:400px;
  position: relative;
}

#slideshow { 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  position: relative; 
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}

#slideshow > .slideImg { 
  position: absolute; 
}

#slideshow img{
  width:100%;
  min-height:300px;
  height:400px
}
```

Comment: Link isn't working.

Comment: @andrescpacheco Extremely sorry Please try this http://foxboxretail.com/

Answer (score 0):

No Problem. First image shows first when I checked. see **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lmbj6yg/)**

```js
$("#slideshow > .slideImg:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function () {
  $('#slideshow > .slideImg:first')
  .fadeOut(1000)
  .next()
  .fadeIn(1000)
  .end()
  .appendTo('#slideshow');
}, 3000);
```

```css
.main-banner {
  background: #444;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height:400px;
  position: relative;
}

#slideshow { 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  position: relative; 
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}

#slideshow > .slideImg { 
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

#slideshow img{
  width:100%;
  min-height:300px;
  height:400px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-banner">
  <div id="slideshow">
    <div class="slideImg">
      <img src="http://cdn3.aukera.es/blog/imagenes/google-tag-manager-for-dummies.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="slideImg">
      <img src="http://www.europeanprospects.org/sites/default/files/styles/editorial/public/image_188537642667430843.jpg?itok=zE3T4v9G" />
    </div>

    <div class="slideImg">
      <img src="http://www.spodestorage.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/dummy.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="slideImg">
      <img src="http://purvknowledge.com/userfiles/galleries/o_8-390.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!--main-banner-ends-->
```

Comment: Please visit  this link http://foxboxretail.com/ .. I don't understand why that problem is coming

Comment: can you just reload it. This is the same domain. I clicked on link it shown error but when I refreshed It worked.